# PHP Paypal IPN Integration

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have been using the paypal ipn for the buyout option in my site.The ipn process requires various hidden fields to pass through the payment gateway.Some of the hidden fields such amount,price,billing_email.

```
<div class="payorder_det">      
<div class="payorder_qtydet">
    <div class="payorder_qtyno">
        <label>Please choose your Card Quantity:</label>
    </div>
<div class="payorder_qtyinfo">
<input type="radio" name="quantity" value="100" onclick="changeamount(this)" checked>100 
<input type="radio" name="quantity" value="250" onclick="changeamount(this)"> 250 
<input type="radio" name="quantity" value="1000" onclick="changeamount(this)">1000 
</div> 
<div class="payorder_qtyinfo">
    <label><b>Price:</b> &nbsp;</label>
    $<input id="amount" name="amount" value="20" 
    style="width:50px;border:none" readonly="true"></input>
</div>
</div>
<div class="payorder_qtydet">
    <input type="submit" value="" name="paypal" class="paypalbtn">
</div> 
</div>
```

The current proces works correctly by calculating the Total=Quantity*Price. So in the paypal its shows EX: itemprice:$10 and quantity=100 in the total amount column it shows $1,000. But in my application , i need the total to be same as the original price ie.$10 only. Please suggest any ideas to get this field value as per the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please suggest any ideas to get this field value as per the requirement.

Pass it differently to paypal. In the PP cart details, append the number of items in parenthesis and set the quantity to 1, i.e. "some stuff (100), 1, $10" rather than "some stuff, 100, $10".

Comment: i am not having in a cart, its was just some radion button with their corresponding values.Please suggest any other method.

Comment: It's the same thing: you're passing a quantity at some point in your form, which is being applied/interpreted differently over on PP. You need to go through the PP docs and modify your code accordingly.